# Send PushNotification to ParseUser matching query?

Tags: android, parse-platform

Im trying to send a PushNotification to all ParseUsers, that have a paticular 'username' added in their friends-list. "friends"(KEY) & "userA"(VALUE).

```
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("friends", "userA");

    ParsePush pPush = new ParsePush();
    pPush.setQuery(query);
    pPush.setMessage("HeyNuclerExlosion! <!-!>");
    pPush.sendInBackground();
```

under `pPush.setQuery(query)` , I get the following error.

```
The method setQuery(ParseQuery<ParseInstallation>) in the type ParsePush is 
not applicable for the arguments (ParseQuery<ParseUser>)
```

Ive been able to send a PushNotificaiton using `ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> query = ParseInstallation.getQuery()` , but this would be device specific.

I want to know how I can query the ParseUser class and send a PushNotification?

Edit: One way to do this is by playing with the "user" (KEY). Here's what im doing when the user logs in&out respectively. And am querying `<ParseInstallation>`

```
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().put("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().put("user","null");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while storing data to the user table make one column to installation table
```

and store the user name like this..

```
 ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
            installation.put("user_name", "name of user");
            installation.saveInBackground();
```

you can update it whenever you want to....

and send the push to the user that you want to target...

```
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
query.whereEqualTo("user_name", "name of user");
```

Comment: hey thats exactly what I did! Also for others reading the answer, in the query, where param has written "name of user"  ; it can either be a `String value` or an `ArrayList`

Answer (score 1):

You don't send pushes to users but to installations, so I think you're on the right track by associating users with installations.

Comment: Yup. One hack I figured was to assign a user channels, and copy it to an installation when he signs in, and remove them when the user signs out. Will update it with a solution once im done. Thanks :)

Comment: probably should associate an installation with a user, that way if there are multiple users using the device, they all can receive the same push notification to the device